# What does map in Scala do

Tags: scala, collections, dictionary

Can somebody explain what does map on Lists exactly do in Scala? 
For example the following line of code:

```
map(row => row(column))
```

Comment: tried google already?

Answer (score 1):

`map` does transformation by applying a function to each element, your example is hard to read without more code, simple example is

```
scala> val l = List(1,2,3)
scala> l.map( x => x*2 )
res1: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6)
```

Comment: My code: def column(c: Int): List[Int] = {(grid.map(x => x(c))} where grid is a list of lists